# Can I programatically set spring profile that will choose an application.properties file to pull from?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I am starting a new spring application and want to use spring profiles along with unique properties files that correspond to different regions:

application-dev.properties, application-live.properties, etc.

So in order to determine which profile I want to use I have to go through some code in a 'startup' function I've written. It basically checks my business region, how it is being run, etc. and sets the active spring profile based on that info. This part works fine and as expected.

My issue is that once I set the profile Spring doesn't start pulling from my custom profiled application-*profile*.properties files. Instead it tries to grab from the default (if I have one) or just returns null for the properties I try and access. Is this not a feature spring has? Does my profile have to be set and in stone before runtime?

Here is how I am setting the active profile:

```
configurableEnvironment.setActiveProfiles("dev");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the active profile in two ways

> The Spring Environment has an API for this, but normally you would set
>   a System property (spring.profiles.active) or an OS environment
>   variable (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE). E.g. launch your application with a
>   -D argument (remember to put it before the main class or jar archive):

```
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

> In Spring Boot you can also set the active profile in
>   application.properties, e.g.

```
spring.profiles.active=production
```

> A value set this way is replaced by the System property or environment
>   variable setting, but not by the SpringApplicationBuilder.profiles()
>   method. Thus the latter Java API can be used to augment the profiles
>   without changing the defaults.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles

Comment: So I am able to set the active profile but the problem is that I do this after launch. At this point the ConfigurableEnvironment already has its properties loaded and it won't pick up new properties for some reason.